# How to parse Valid Instance from RDF Turtle file?

Tags: java, parsing, rdf, jena, turtle-rdf

I have a RDF file in turtle format. An example of this is given below:

```
qb4o:level rdf:type rdf:Property, owl:ObjectProperty ;
        rdfs:label "level"@en ;
        rdfs:comment "An alternative to qb:componentProperty which makes explicit that the component is a level"@en ;
        rdfs:subPropertyOf qb:componentProperty ;
        rdfs:isDefinedBy <http://purl.org/qb4olap/cubes> ;
        rdfs:range qb4o:LevelProperty .

### http://purl.org/qb4olap/cubes#memberOf
qb4o:memberOf rdf:type rdf:Property, owl:ObjectProperty ;
        rdfs:label "level member is member of level"@en ;
        rdfs:comment "Indicates the level to which the level member belongs"@en ;
        rdfs:isDefinedBy <http://purl.org/qb4olap/cubes> ;
        rdfs:domain qb4o:LevelMember ;
        rdfs:range qb4o:LevelProperty .
```

Now, I need to parse the instances from this file. I can do that using Sparql in Jena. But, the problem is that there may remain some invalid instances for which I can't load them in Jena Model. An example of this is given below:

```
qb4o:level rdf:type rdf:Property, owl:ObjectProperty ;
        rdfs:label "level"@en ;
        rdfs:comment "An alternative to qb:componentProperty which makes explicit that the component is a level"@en ;
        rdfs:subPropertyOf qb:componentProperty ;
        rdfs:isDefinedBy <http://purl.org/qb4olap/cubes> ;
        rdfs:range qb4o:LevelProperty .

### http://purl.org/qb4olap/cubes#memberOf
qb4o:memberOf rdf:type rdf:Property, owl:ObjectProperty ;
        rdfs:label "level member is member of level"@en ;
        rdfs:comment "Indicates the level to which the level member belongs"@en ;
        rdfs:isDefinedBy <http://purl.org/qb4olap/cubes> ;
```

So, I decided to parse them using regex. But, I can't figure out the regex to ignore the invalid instances and take only the correct instances. It is a bit difficult because the turtle file can be in this format also:

```
<http://example/check/ontology/householdSize#1>
        a       <http://example/check/ontology#Size> ;
        <http://example/check/ontology#name>
                "1 person" ;
        <http://example/check/ontology#id>
                "1" .

<http://example/check/ontology/householdSize#2>
        a       <http://example/check/ontology#Size> ;
        <http://example/check/ontology#name>
                "2 person" ;
        <http://example/check/ontology#id>
                "2" .
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is "invalid"? Maybe you mean that the `qb4o:memberOf` stanza didn't end with a `.`? Turtle files are generally best handled with Turtle parsers, especially if you're working with the RDF as such. It often helps us help you, if you can give us more of a big-picture of what you're trying to do, and why -- as specific small issues may be avoidable by a change at a larger step.

Comment: Yes, by validating, I mean detecting instances that don't end with a dot. I want to differentiate the instances that don't end with a dot and then ignore them. 
@TallTed Actually, what I am trying to do is, if a file contains errors like this, Jena doesn't load them into a model. But I want to ignore those invalid instances if any exists and then load them into the Jena model so that I can run Sparql Queries on them.

Comment: just adapt the Jena RDF parser with some fault tolerance mechanism, which skips those parse errors and continues. Indeed, the "better" way would be to fix the root error, i.e. the data itself or even better the tool that produced the data.